# C# TransactionScope - keep state cliente x server

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

I'm in a project to upgrade a application from visual basic 5 to ASP.Net MVC.

In a specific screen, the user fills a lot of information about a product and activates the save function.

In the save function there are a TransactionScope to control transaction between the database upgrades.

After insert a new row in the table, multiples triggers are triggered on database. Besides that, inside the same transaction are make updates in another tables. After all the process, it's necessary to check a specific situation to identify inconsistencies. If they are found I need to ask the user if he wants to continue or end the process. If it chooses to continue, the transaction must be committed. Otherwise rollback.

My problem is: How to keep the state of the transaction while go to the client to ask the user? Is it possible to generate some kind of token or something to recover this transaction?

Comment: Keeping a transaction running for long periods of time is a bad idea, especially if it spans multiple tables or tables that are written to frequently.

What sort of "inconsistencies" are you talking about in this case, which require the user's intervention?

Comment: @easuter These "inconsistencies" may be generated after user-made changes. It is complicated to detail them without knowing the context / concept of the application. If this happens, it is necessary for the user to be aware and conscientiously confirm the process.

Comment: In that case it's a bit hard to propose a solution. If the inconsistencies are related to a bad database model (not enough normalization, lack of unique keys and referential integrity), then it doesn't make sense to try to insert the data first and then have the user review the changes. You'd either need to fix your DB model or if you can't then compile a list of *proposed* changes before actually inserting/updating any data.

If you can share more then it may be possible for more users to jump in and help you...

Comment: Definitely do not hold a transaction open waiting for user input. Just saying that out loud you can hear how bad an idea it is. I am inclined to believe that the source of your problem is actually the unpredictability of your database, or at least the mechanisms that write to it. Whether you resolve that problem now or later, I do recommend that you resolve it, and it will hurt less to do it sooner rather than later.

Comment: It is more complex than a simple primary key check or referential integrity. In some cases a message is send to SAP by WebSphere MQ and depending on the return message the user must confirm or not proceed. Database normalization is OK!

Comment: The case you've just described can't really be atomic, as you have no control over the behaviour of these external resources. The way I'd try to tackle this is to: (1) identify how much of the work can be done in a reversible manner; (2) only present the user with a *proposed* set of changes based on the DB's state at the time, and the results of your SAP response; (3) if the user accepts, then try to carry out the requested changes, and fail/rollback if your DB's state has changed by other actors so as to make the request invalid.